# SQL points around line between A and B

Tags: sql, sql-server, geometry

In SQL Server 2014, I have a database with Geometry points - `City`

Driving from City A to City B gives me a line (we take an airplane).

I need to find points in my database - which are in certain distance (10 miles) "off-track" of this line.

I know how to find the closest points around a single point, how to calculate the distance between them - but - how can I search along this line? Like POI in your Navi...

```
DECLARE @g geography 

SELECT @g = Geo_LatLong_deg 
FROM airports 
WHERE iata_code = 'MyAirportCode' -- radius 100km 

SELECT * 
FROM airports 
WHERE @g.STDistance(Geo_LatLong_deg) <= 100000
```

Comment: include sample data with expected output

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? People tend to respond to *specific* questions e.g. "I am doing X and it mainly works except for Y when Z happens. How can I stop Z happening?", rather than "I want to do X, please give me the algorithm to do it".

Comment: I used this to get the points around the "endpoints" A and B:
DECLARE @g geography
SELECT @g = Geo_LatLong_deg FROM airports  where iata_code='MyAirportCode'

-- radius 100km
SELECT * FROM airports WHERE @g.STDistance(Geo_LatLong_deg) <= 100000

Comment: Please explain your data model and table structure, provide sample data, provide your approach so far, what's the output of your approach and what outcome you expect

Comment: Create the polygon geometry around the line and from points in your DB then intersects them.

Comment: My Table has CityName, Longitude (decimal), Latitude, Geo (Geography Location based on earth surface).
I like to get everything what is between them.
I will give the Polygon a shot. Idea how to get the parallels from a circle to circle (radius x Meter around Point A/B).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [STBuffer method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933965.aspx). Assuming that you've got some way to determine your path as a geography instance, it's as simple as:

```
declare @distance float = 16.09344 --10 miles in km

select *
from airports
where @path.STBuffer(@distance).STIntersects(Geo_LatLong_deg) = 1
```

By way of explanation, the `STBuffer()` method creates a region that is the set of points within 10 miles of your path. Then, we select all points from your table that intersect with that region with `STIntersects()`.

Comment: now I got the line - created from two points - but still I have a problem to get the STBuffer/STIntersects running... as I get no results - even not from  A or B Point - which is "on the line"

`
SET @BuildString = 'LINESTRING(' + @BuildString + ')';   
DECLARE @LineFromPoints geography = geography::STLineFromText(@BuildString, 4326);
--SELECT @LineFromPoints

declare @distance float = 160.9344 --100 miles in km

select *
from airports
where @LineFromPoints.STBuffer(@distance).STIntersects(Geo_LatLong_deg) = 1 `
is the LineFromPoints=Path?

Comment: Hmm... you should be getting at least the endpoints of the line. Take a look at both the line and the buffer around the line in SSMS (if you `select @LineFromPoints`, it will give you another tab that shows the geography instance on a map. Similarly for the buffer. Does the line make sense? One thing that trips me up is that the order of longitude and latitude are different than I expect (so I have to look it up every time).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. I mixed up Long/Lat sequence in string... now I get the results as expected.
here the code - if others want to see how to combine two or more points - together with the area around the line(s).

```
    DECLARE @BuildString NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @BuildString = COALESCE(@BuildString + ',', '') + CAST(longitude_deg AS NVARCHAR(50)) + ' ' + CAST(latitude_deg AS NVARCHAR(50))
FROM dbo.airports where iata_code='RLG' or iata_code='FRA'
ORDER BY ID             

SET @BuildString = 'LINESTRING(' + @BuildString + ')';   
DECLARE @LineFromPoints geography = geography::STLineFromText(@BuildString, 4326);

declare @distance float = 50000 

select *
from airports
where @LineFromPoints.STBuffer(@distance).STIntersects(airports.GEO_LatLong_deg) = 1 and type<>'heliport'
```